# What can i say about L1 given that L2, L1L2 and L2L1 are regular?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, closure-properties

I found this question in one of our past exams, and I'm not to sure about the correct answer.

I have a language L1 (which i don't know anything about) and another language **L2**, which is regular, the question is: given that **L1L2**, **L2L1** are regular can i also say for sure that L1 is regular?

At first my answer was no, since I cannot say anything about the original languages given their regular concatenation;
But then I thought : Wouldn't I be able to extract the DFA or regex for the first language since I have both L1L2 and L2L1?

Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about it a bit after posting the question and came up with a counter-example for the second (and wrong) assumption:

L1 = { 0^p | p is a prime number} (Not a regular language), L2 = 0* (regular); Both the concatenations are regular since they become L1L2 = L2L1 = { 000* } ;

Thank you all for the help and for correcting my mistakes    :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer was right I'd say. Consider **L2** could be $\emptyset$. It's regular and both concatenations are equally regular. We won't learn anything about **L1** though.

Comment: I also came up with a counter-example for the second answer, L1 = { 0^p | p is a prime number} (Not a regular language), L2 = 0* (regular); Both the concatenations are regular since they become L1L2 = L2L1 =  { 0* } ;
I Hope everything is correct.